# I need to count the number of consecutive zeroes and update the new array with such count. each such block of zeroes has to be counted separately

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I need to count consecutive blocks which are filled with zero and update the array `result` with each block separately like this `[3,2,5]`

This is my attempt, but it gives me the total number of zeros `[10]`.

**Also i need to return the Position of first Element of each Block in another array like this [2,6,11].**

```js
var A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var N = A.length;

function AvailConseblocks(A) {
  var counter = 0;
  var result = [];
  var POS = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] === 0) {
      counter++;
      POS.push(i)
    }
  }
  result.push(counter);
  return result
}

console.log(AvailConseblocks(A));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, not tested for edge cases.

```js
var A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var N = A.length;

function AvailConseblocks(A) {
    var counter = 0;
    var result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] === 0) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            // if element is not zero and counter is not zero as well
            // means we found 0 or 0's surrounded by non-zero elements
            // we push the counter and re-intialize it to zero
            if (counter !== 0) {
                result.push(counter);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // this is important if  last element of the array was zero as well
    if (counter !== 0) {
        result.push(counter);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(AvailConseblocks(A));
```

Comment: May you add a description as to what you changed?

Comment: @ Ashu , can I return the position of the first elements of each block like this [2,6,11] in another array ?

Answer (score 4):

```js
let arr = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

let result =arr.join('').split(/[^0]/g).filter(e => e).map(e => e.length)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can I return the position of the first elements of each block like this [2,6,11] in another array ?

Answer (score 1):

It can do the job done

```js
const countNumbers = (count) => {

let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {

    arr = arr.concat(count[i]);
}

let zero = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i] === 0) zero++;

}

return zero;

};

console.log(countNumbers([2, 3, 44, 0, 0, 0, 00])); // ans : 4
```